# Making sense of mod_tiles /[TileSetName]/Z/X/Y.png tile serving

Tags: python, mod-tile

I am trying to understand this part of mod_tile documentation about tile serving:

```
Apache serves the files as if they were present under /[TileSetName]/Z/X/Y.png with the path being converted automatically.
```

To be sure, I have little experience with Apache. So, I kind of have to make sense of this. Does this mean that if mod_tile is running, I can open use Python with pillow to open a png-file in lets say "/tilename/17/51.5072/0.1276" to get a map of London at zoom-level 17 using tiles with TileSetName=tilename?

Or, do I have to send a get request to localhost "http://localhost/tilename/17/51.5072/0.1276"?

And how do I adjust the size of the PNG?

Answer (score 1):

You do have to use http://localhost/tilename/17/51.5072/0.1276 as there are no real file under "tilename/17/51.5072/0.1276" on the machine path. The explanation is from the project doc itself (https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile#details-about-mod_tile-tile-serving)

> To avoid problems with directories becoming too large and to avoid too many tiny files. They store the rendered tiles in "meta tiles" in a special hashed directory structure. These combine 8x8 actual tiles into a single metatile file. This is a more efficient use of disk space and inodes.

> The metatiles are then stored in the following directory structure: /[base_dir]/[TileSetName]/[Z]/[xxxxyyyy]/[xxxxyyyy]/[xxxxyyyy]/[xxxxyyyy]/[xxxxyyyy].meta

Imagining you choose to open the metatiles to get png from it (using provided utility like [`convert_meta`](https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile/blob/master/docs/man/convert_meta.1)) if you don't do the call to Apache first, you will no have the required metatiles.

For the output quality, "on the paper", you should be able to play with Mapnik options e.g https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/Image-IO#png-output-options  but to be honest, I never changed them so not sure about it, in particular with the abstract level of mml if you are using [official OpenStreetMap style](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/project.mml#L14).